# if statement condition doesn't work when comparing the value from array

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have a problem,  this is my code and the goal of it is that after login it redirects to one or another page.

```
function my_login_redirect(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user1 = $current_user->ID;
    $meta = get_user_meta($user1, 'kundenumber');

    if ($meta == '' ) {
        // return the url that the login should redirect to
        $var = 'http://www.example1.com';
    } else {
        $var = 'http://www.example2.com';
    }

    return $var;
}
```

It always returns the first link (I have two users these are they var dumps for 'kundenumber' field)

```
 array(1) { [0]=> string( 0 ) "" }
 array(1) { [0]=> string( 6 ) "123456" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

So you need to set third parameter as true to get `value` not `array` :

```
$meta = get_user_meta($user1, 'kundenumber', true );
```

Comment: when I set it to true I get  int(2) when i do the var_dump(for the second user(second array))

Comment: According to doc after setting **third** param to true, you should receive empty string for first user and '123456' for second user. Are you sure you change correctly third parameter? Show me exaclty result of var_dump($meta); for both users

Comment: first is string(0) "" and second is string(6) "123456". you were correct but it still redirects to first site

Comment: before `return $var;` put `var_dump($var);` to make sure that `$var` is set correctly

Comment: one question how to do var_dump in function.php

Comment: Y.. and how did you var_dump string '123456' ?

Comment: I dumped it contact.php template of wordpress, and it showed after you loged in... ups, sry foolish question

Comment: just do `var_dump($var);die('testing');` before return

Comment: before I loged in it says http://www.example1.com', but after login(after i return from redirected page) it says http://www.example2.com'

Comment: so it should work, it has right link, right? So it means that some of your redirect wp script does not work properly or you set it wrong. Problem with getting meta value is fixed now. Now you have another problem why your redirect wp script does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`get_user_meta()` returns an array. You're comparing the whole array to an empty string. You should compare the string in the array to an empty string like `if ($meta[0] == '')`

Answer (score 0):

This means $meta is empty. There are two possibility for empty $meta -
1)Use of wrong key.
2)$user_id is not set or is set to an incorrect value.